# CMake ExternalProject does not unpack dependencies

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio, cmake, dependency-management

I am building an application which uses `tinyxml2` and few other dependencies (namely `Irrlicht` and `IrrKlang`) that I provide as `.zip` files in the `Dependency` subdirectory of my project:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Dependencies
│   ├── irrKlang-1.5.0.zip
│   ├── irrKlang-32bit-1.5.0.zip
│   ├── irrKlang-64bit-1.5.0.zip
│   ├── irrlicht-1.8.4.zip
│   └── tinyxml2-master.zip
├── Editor
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── Sources
│       └── main.cpp
└── Game
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── Sources
        └── main.cpp
```

***NOTE:*** for a reference, full sources are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/shybovycha/shoot-them/tree/rework-2020), here I cut some corners to make the question shorter.

The top-level `CMakeFiles.txt` is set up is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

project(shoot-them VERSION 1.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

include(ExternalProject)

# few platform-specific variables like MAKE_COMMAND, PLATFORM_ARCH, etc.

# libraries (see below)

add_subdirectory(Game)
add_subdirectory(Editor
```

Both `Irrlicht` and `IrrKlang` come with pre-built libraries for Windows for x86, but not for Windows x64 and not for OSX. Hence I add it as a dependency like this (using the `if(NOT IRRLICHT_LIBRARY_PATH)` just to separate the code into a block:

```
if(NOT IRRLICHT_LIBRARY_PATH)
    ExternalProject_Add(irrlicht-dep
        URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Dependencies/irrlicht-1.8.4.zip
        PREFIX Dependencies/irrlicht
        SOURCE_SUBDIR source/Irrlicht
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_COMMAND "${MAKE_COMMAND}"
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )

    ExternalProject_Get_Property(irrlicht-dep SOURCE_DIR)
    set(IRRLICHT_PATH ${SOURCE_DIR})

    add_library(irrlicht SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

    set_target_properties(
        irrlicht PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${IRRLICHT_PATH}/lib/${IRRLICHT_PATH_SUFFIX}/Irrlicht${CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${IRRLICHT_PATH}/lib/${IRRLICHT_PATH_SUFFIX}/Irrlicht${CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${IRRLICHT_PATH}/include
    )
endif()
```

I follow the same principles for `IrrKlang`. But since `tinyxml2` comes as a header and a source file and it comes packed with `CMakeLists.txt`, I just include it like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(tinyxml2-dep
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Dependencies/tinyxml2-master.zip
    PREFIX Dependencies/tinyxml2
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(tinyxml2-dep SOURCE_DIR)
set(TINYXML2_PATH ${SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(${TINYXML2_PATH})
```

I define both `Game` and `Editor` sub-projects as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Editor VERSION 1.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME Editor)

set(SOURCES Sources/main.cpp)

# platform-specific variables

set_target_properties(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    CXX_EXTENSIONS ON
)

add_dependencies(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} tinyxml2 irrlicht)

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIBRARIES} tinyxml2 irrlicht)

if(NOT APPLE)
    # Copy libraries' DLLs
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:tinyxml2> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${EXECUTABLE_NAME}>
    )
endif()

# TODO: copy DLLs, not LIBs
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:irrlicht> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${EXECUTABLE_NAME}>
)
```

The way I use `ExternalProject` specifically is because

1. I wanted to fix the versions I build my project with
2. I did not want to pollute my system with installing the libraries (hence no `INSTALL` steps, although I may completely misunderstand that concept)
3. I do not depend on 3rd party repositories being dead (hence shipping the ZIP files with the sources)
4. I do not rely on unbelievably outdated (and thus potentially non-working) find modules for CMake

To be fair: I am not aware of any best practices of building projects with CMake, so I might very well be completely wrong about all of the above, so **please do correct me**.

When I build this project in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows, it works like a charm. But whenever I try building the thing on OSX, I get failures:

1. none of the dependencies gets even unpacked
2. *(because of p.1)* the `${TINYXML2_DIR}` is never set
3. *(because of p.2)* the `tinyxml2` directory could not be found and thus added via `add_subdirectory()`
4. *(because of p.3)* the `$<TARGET_FILE:tinyxml2>` expression does not evaluate
5. *(as a global consequence)* the project does not build

The way I build project is rather simple:

```
cmake -Bbuild -H. && cmake --build build
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, what is the right way to handle 3rd party dependencies with CMake?

I am very well aware that CMake is *technically* just a *makefile* (roughly speaking, since it is different for every build toolchain) generator, so my question is more about how do I tell CMake to generate the correct build files for each type of dependency that should be built with my project (pre-built, build from sources with CMake, build from sources with a custom command). I thought `ExternalProject` is supposed to handle just that, but apparently something went horribly wrong along the way.

Comment: You should try to use FetchContent() which is at configure time, since ExternalProject is performed at build time or you need to use this trick to force external project at configure time: https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played with both a solution suggested by @Mizux in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64041827/cmake-externalproject-does-not-unpack-dependencies#comment113276989_64041827) and had some success with two different approaches.

### 1. vcpkg

This is arguably the easier of the two. It requires [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) installed.

See [this commit](https://github.com/shybovycha/shoot-them/commit/0f2df43d12c1214b1ba1c65b900e892e0a58d274) for example.

Create a manifest file, `vcpkg.json` in the project root directory, listing all the dependencies used by the project:

```
{
    "name": "PROJECT_NAME",
    "version-string": "0.1.0",
    "dependencies": [
        "irrlicht",
        "tinyxml2"
    ]
}
```

You can also use CLI to generate the manifest by using `vcpkg install` command.

Use the `find_package` from CMake to link libraries to each target - in the child `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(irrlicht CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(tinyxml2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIBRARIES} tinyxml2::tinyxml2 Irrlicht)
```

**Important:** when configuring the project, pass the path to the vcpkg CMake module:

```
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

### 2. FetchContent + ExternalProject

Since my project depends on both a library that ships with `CMakeLists.txt` and a library that does not, this is a nice example.

See [this commit](https://github.com/shybovycha/shoot-them/commit/331ce9145d1145d3d6c05afc0454cec8453102d7) for example.

First, as @Mizux mentioned, `FetchContent` works at configure time - it downloads and unpacks the dependency when you configure the project (call `cmake -S . -B build`). Then, since `irrlicht` does not ship with `CMakeLists.txt`, you either use `ExternalProject_Add` to build it with custom command (`make` in my case) or add it as a sub-directory to the project.

`FetchContent` part:

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(irrlicht
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Dependencies/irrlicht-1.8.4.zip
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(irrlicht)

if(NOT irrlicht_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(irrlicht)
endif()

set(IRRLICHT_PATH ${irrlicht_SOURCE_DIR})
```

`ExternalProject` part:

```
include(ExternalProject)

if(NOT WIN32)
    ExternalProject_Add(irrlicht-dep
        SOURCE_DIR "${IRRLICHT_PATH}/source/Irrlicht"
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE true
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_COMMAND "${MAKE_COMMAND}"
    )
endif()

add_library(irrlicht SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set_target_properties(
    irrlicht PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${IRRLICHT_PATH}/lib/${IRRLICHT_PATH_SUFFIX}/Irrlicht${CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${IRRLICHT_PATH}/lib/${IRRLICHT_PATH_SUFFIX}/Irrlicht${CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${IRRLICHT_PATH}/include
)
```

Note the important bits in the `ExternalProject` configuration:

- `irrlicht_SOURCE_DIR` variable is populated by `FetchContent`
- `SOURCE_DIR "${irrlicht_SOURCE_DIR}/source/Irrlicht"` - tells `ExternalProject` where the **unpacked sources** are; if this directory is not empty (which it should be not, since `FetchContent` should have populated it at project configuration time), `ExternalProject` will skip the download phase
- `BUILD_IN_SOURCE true` - builds from within the source directory
- `CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""` - skips the dependency configuration phase, so not `cmake` will be executed for the dependency
- `BUILD_COMMAND "make"` - uses a specific command to build the dependency from sources
- `if(NOT WIN32)` - only uses `ExternalProject` to **build** the dependency; since Irrlicht comes with pre-built libraries for `Win32`, this should build the thing for the other platforms (including `Win64`)